# Exclude file/path with square brackets from jest coverage

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, code-coverage, glob

I want to exclude a file from test coverage by adding an entry to [`collectCoverageFrom` for Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array) which has square brackets in the file name. Jest

```ts
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!./src/some/path/to/[fileWithSquareBrackets].ts',
  ]
```

This does not prevent test coverage from being collected for this file, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the square brackets, as they are special characters for glob patterns, which Jest uses. Either of the following work:

```ts
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!./src/some/path/to/[[]fileWithSquareBrackets[]].ts',
  ]
```

```ts
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!./src/some/path/to/\\[fileWithSquareBrackets\\].ts',
  ]
```

I slightly prefer the latter, as it is actually escaping the bracket, rather than using the bracket to signify a glob character class containing a square bracket.